# How do I get the first non-null value from multiple columns based on another datetime column order and grouped by ID?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I've got right now is a DataFrame like this:

```
    id  ts                          site   type
0   111 2022-07-25 19:07:00.938365  A      NaN
1   111 2022-07-25 19:07:00.938371  NaN    1.0
2   222 2022-07-25 19:07:00.938372  NaN    NaN
3   222 2022-07-25 19:07:00.938373  NaN    2.0
4   222 2022-07-25 19:07:00.938374  C      1.0
```

What I'm trying to do is get the first non-null values of `site` and `type` for each `id`, based on the descending order of `ts`.

So my expected output is something like:

```
    id  site   type
0   111 A      1.0
1   222 C      1.0
```

I've tried to do this:

```
df_grouped = df.sort_values(by="ts", ascending=False).groupby("id").ffill().first()


> TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
```

I've also tried this:

```
df_grouped[["site", "type"]].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index()).reset_index()



    index       0
0   site        0
1   screen_type 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(df.sort_values('ts', ascending=False).bfill().groupby('id')[['site', 'type']]
   .agg(lambda x:x.bfill().head(1)).reset_index())

    id site  type
0  111    A   1.0
1  222    C   1.0
```

Note that if YOU ARE SURE there is ATLEAST 1 NON-NAN per id then you can do:

```
(df.sort_values('ts', ascending=False).bfill().groupby('id')[['site', 'type']]
   .first().reset_index())

    id site  type
0  111    A   1.0
1  222    C   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm marking your answer as correct because it deals with the possibility of having null values, which probably is my case (there are millions of rows overall).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
df = df.sort_values('ts', ascending=False)

df.groupby('id', as_index=False)[['site', 'type']].agg(lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0])
```

or using `first_valid_index`:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False)[['site', 'type']].agg(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()])
```

output:

```
    id site  type
0  111    A   1.0
1  222    C   1.0
```

Note: If you have all NaNs in either 'site' or 'type' columns it won't work. Then you don't even have to do this probably.